# Нет подключения в клиенте к серверу через Socket.io, хотя сервер говорит обратно. Постоянное подключение и дисконнект

Tags: node.js, express, react-native, socket.io

Уже который час бьюсь с недопонимаем, надеюсь, сможете помочь(

Версии socket.io:
на клиенте - 3.1.2
на сервере - 1.3.7

Сервер:

```
io.on('connection', (socket) => {
    console.log(`connected ${socket.id}`);

    socket.on('STREAM_STARTED', ioResponse);
    socket.on('MESSAGE_ADD', ioAddMessage);

    socket.on('disconnect', () => {
        console.log(`disconnect ${socket.id}`);
        if(state.connection){
            bot.telegram.sendMessage(state.chatId, ' Соединение закрыто!' + '\n' + 'Оператор вне сети!');
        }
    })
});
```

Клиент:

```
const socket = io(RN_APP_API_URL, {
        autoConnect: false,
        transports: ['websocket'], 
        upgrade: false,
        forceNew: false,
        timeout: 10000
    })

    socket.on('connection', (data) => console.log(1))

    React.useEffect(() => socket.connect(), []);

    socket.on('connect', () => console.log(socket.id))

    console.log(socket.connected);
```

При подключении с клиента по сокетам, сервер говорит что подключение есть и пишет об этом в консоль,
но клиент говорит, что подключения нет и ни на какие события не реагирует.

Также, постоянно идет подключение к серверу:

```
disconnect WpGmWMILxDs8FxoZAAAh
disconnect WpGmWMILxDs8FxoZAAAh
disconnect fFtdvAxPYMpJVdq2AAAi
disconnect fFtdvAxPYMpJVdq2AAAi
connected riQ5lraHl9Pf4u8NAAAo
connected riQ5lraHl9Pf4u8NAAAo
disconnect hRjatYCXqkwGOkqrAAAj
disconnect hRjatYCXqkwGOkqrAAAj
connected ltn1DI0iWSCm72HvAAAp
connected FTWsnzIFY7Wc0INPAAAq
connected ltn1DI0iWSCm72HvAAAp
connected FTWsnzIFY7Wc0INPAAAq
disconnect 7ugnRPGL0LOqta44AAAk
disconnect 7ugnRPGL0LOqta44AAAk
connected Uyq_WTNzpidPX8OmAAAr
connected Uyq_WTNzpidPX8OmAAAr
connected Iwx4XZafqc_XZwU4AAAs
connected Iwx4XZafqc_XZwU4AAAs
disconnect rFF6fYN7SX3AHWzSAAAl
disconnect rFF6fYN7SX3AHWzSAAAl
connected N4nRZajVofIIjjpiAAAt
connected N4nRZajVofIIjjpiAAAt
disconnect pLdKHP_6Hi6Kui7KAAAm
disconnect pLdKHP_6Hi6Kui7KAAAm
connected pWzWCuU-vP0Huo8wAAAu
connected pWzWCuU-vP0Huo8wAAAu
```

Тоже не понимаю почему так происходит

Comment: Никто не сможет помочь?(

Answer (score 1):

https://socket.io/docs/v4/client-installation/#Version-compatibility
У вас несовместимые версии на сервере и клиенте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]